ethers.toBigInt(...).eq is not a function
I’m using ethers v6 and comparing the converted numbers, but I’m facing this error:
TypeError: ethers.toBigInt(...).eq is not a function


If changing the version doesn't work, please provide the complete code so I can assist you more effectively. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish.

In ethers v6, instead of eq you’ve to use the == operator for equality comparison, like:
value1 = ethers.toBigInt("1000");
value2 = ethers.toBigInt("1000");
isEqual = (value1 == value2);

You can refer to the Big Numbers migration section of the ethers v6 doc.

I think You need to try the ether.js 5.7.2 version as it is stable and works.
npm install ethers@5.7.2

Or
yarn add ethers@5.7.2

